# Textpad Custom Document classes color settings

Tags: syntax, colors, color-scheme, textpad

I am trying to setup a Custom Document class in TextPad. I copied the pre-existing c.syn file (syntax color scheme for C language), adjusted as needed, but I have a couple of additional situations that I cannot figure put how to setup.

It works fine for keywords who only contain words, followed or preceded by spaces (e.g.:
for
goto
if
int
long
main
register
return).

But I would also like to have the following two situations to be included in keywords:

- lines that start with certain text (e.g.:"kwtext;" - if the line starts with "kw", highlight either the whole line all the way to ";" or just the "kw")
- structures like ";c=", which will be always in the middle of the line ("=" is already defined as a OperatorChar, so it will be greyed out by default, even if I define "c=" or ";c=" as keyword)

Is there any workaround to such situations?

Thanks a lot in advance for any ideas!

Comment: I think has a higher chance of being answered in the [TextPad user forums](http://forums.textpad.com/viewforum.php?f=8).

Comment: Looks like those forums are not mderated anymore... I registered, and still waiting for confimation of the account by a mod....

Answer (score 0):

> > lines that start with certain text (e.g.:"kwtext;" - if the line starts with "kw", highlight either the whole line all the way to ";" or just the "kw")

I would advise you use one of the comment line options so instead starting with "//" it starts with "kw".

I don't understand your second question - I'd advise that you split questions in stack overflow as this now becomes answerable only if you answer both which isn't helpful

Answer (score 0):

Registration Issue: See
http://forums.textpad.com/viewtopic.php?t=12634

> If you have recently registered on the TextPad Forum, you will need to
>   contact "support@textpad.com" with your user name, in order for your
>   account to be activated.
>
> This process provides an increased level of security on the Forum.

(I had the same problem).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12225842)

Comment: I'm aware of this. My reputation is not high enough to comment. Therefore I used answer to get horrace_vr informed. In the past I had the same problem as he concerning forum and I was very thankful to get this information in stack overflow by a friendly person.